# How can I save messages from a particular sender in a particular folder in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

A particular sender (an advertising company) sends a lot of emails daily into my Gmail inbox. Now those mails are important to me, since I am interested in their ads, but every time it is not possible to check them all. So I don't want my inbox to be flooded with their emails. Sometimes I can't work properly with my inbox filled with their emails. So is there a way so that I can mark the sender such a way so that the mail comes as usual, but it goes to a specific folder in lieu of flooding my inbox, so that when I get free time I can check their mails entering a particular folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A strength of Gmail is the use of labels, instead of folders.  You need to create a filter to automatically add a label to the message and automaticlly archive the messages.

To create a filer for a message that frequently is sent to you:

1. select or open a message you want to filter
2. Under the **More** pulldown select the command: **Filter messages like these**
3. You will then see the form open up with the **FROM** box filled in.
4. Google with then show you the messages that the filter has found.
5. Click **create filter** with this search.
6. You can now specify if you want to:

   - **Skip the Inbox (Archive it)**
   - **Apply the label:**
   - Also **apply filter to x matching conversations**.
7. Click **create the filter**.

Archiving the messages keeps the message, it just removes the inbox label from the message. Labels can be used to search using label:mylabel. Labels are listed on the sidebar menu so that you can quickly jump to a filter that just shows the messages with that label. Plus messages can have multiple labels.

You can edit/delete/create filters under Settings(gear)->Filter

Comment: BDW now I faced another problem. The sender sends two types of mails.one is "new product launch" another is "popular discount".Now I am interested in the second one.So after creating the filter both type of mails come to the level.So how can I stop mails of first type from entering the level from the same sender?

Comment: just find some difference between the two emails, such as the subject, and edit the filter to only capture the one you want.